# Powershell Byte Array input string invalid format

Tags: powershell, encryption, casting, arrays

I've written a powershell script which changes the password of a local administrator that works well - It sets the password through a config file which contains the encrypted password and the aes key with which it was generated.
Its done the way described here: http://www.adminarsenal.com/admin-arsenal-blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-2

Now we have a management suite which streamlines administration of windoze and linux, and somehow it doesnt pass the aes key right into the script.

If I try to execute it through the management suite, I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert value "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33" to type "System.Byte". Error: "Input string was not in a correct Format."
```

I think the problem is the difference between PS and the management suite to handle variables (Or the black magic Powershell does under the hood which the management suite doesnt). In the script im reading in the aes-key from config file to a variable, which contains the values that are in the error message, which represent the aes key.

Now my question is: How do i get powershell to recognize the aes key as a byte array?

I cannot simply do a `get-content C:\aes_keyfile`, which maybe does the right typecast or whatever, because the streamline process has its own methods, so what I get in the script is the following:

```
$blah = $blahobject.get_variable("aeskey")
$blah
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33
```

I cant do:

```
[byte[]]$new_blah = $blah - Error: Cannot convert value "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33"  to type "System.Byte[]".  Error: "Input string was not in a correct format.""
```

What is the correct format? How can I find out what it is current and what it expects?

Comment: What is `$blahobject` and when you say `$blah = "1,2,3...`, are you overwriting the `$blah` variable with that value or showing what it contains?

Comment: $blahobject is a alias to the management internal function to get the content of the config file.
And the next line should say what $blah contains after get_variable()

Comment: OK, what does `$blah.GetType()` return?

Comment: It returns System.String

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found it out, thanks to your hint with the type:

I had to split it at the comma, so the right way is:

```
[byte[]]$new_blah = $blah.split(",")
```

Now the decryption of the password works.

Thanks a lot :>